# Does the origin's direction of a cartesian coordinate system matter?

Tags: math

In Flash, the 0, 0 origin is at the top-left corner, increasing X means going to the right, increasing y means going towards bottom.
In math at school they taught us the origin at bottom left corner, x increasing to the right and y increasing upwards. I think most charts are based on this one.

If I am using coordinates, should I force my thinking / calculations / formulas while considering where is my 0, 0 located?

They said I'd need math one day, and I laughed at them... :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [easywms.com](http://www.easywms.com/easywms/files/Image/blog/programming/php/03fig01.jpg))</sub>

Generally speaking, coordinate systems on the computer start with `origin (0, 0)` at the top left corner, but it all really depends.

[image]

The `AndEngine` a graphics library for Android has its `origin (0, 0)` at the bottom left of the screen.

[image]
<sub>(source: [wittman at www.math.ucla.edu](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~wittman/10a.1.10w/ccc/ch09/ch09/images/twodim-array.png))</sub>

While `GridWorld` an API used by schools to teach students programming uses an array-based coordinated system (if I may use that term). What that means is the `origin` is at the top-left and instead of moving along the `x-axis` first you move up and down along the `row` or `y-axis` then the `x`. Its just how arrays are created.

Now speaking with regards to the math, its not considerable difficult to convert from on coordinate system to another. Also yes, you should consider where your origin is at. It makes a considerable difference.

For example my rotation point of the object is the center and it will rotation cleanly and nicely around the center.

http://imageshack.us/a/img20/8369/wishb.png

Now lets say my rotation point has moved to the middle left. It would rotate differently.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Different systems use different types of coordinates systems, just as you describe, where e.g. axes can go in different directions.  Another example of a different co-ordinate system is latitude and longitude, which are used for maps and geographical systems, because there are constraints that you need to be aware of when you work with latitude and longitude.  The important thing is to be aware of all the differences, and to be flexible :-).